# how to configure internet email accounts on my website in php

Tags: php, email

I would like to implement a functionality on my website so users can configure their email accounts and start sending n receiving emails (Pretty much like what gmail did ). Can some one shed some light on how to achieve this?

Thanks

Comment: Have you set up a mail server? Set up DNS records? Read anything at all about how administering an email server works? This is a non-trivial problem, but it seems like you haven't made any effort to learn what's required.

Comment: Yeah, i have them setup.. what now? i'm here to know whats required, dont just tell me 'do your own research...'

Comment: You are *expected* to do your own research before coming here to ask questions.

Answer (score 1):

Configure your mailserver to use a database backend. your php application connects to the same database and creates user accounts etc.

more details here: [How to communicate with a mail server through a web application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6423126/how-to-communicate-with-a-mail-server-through-a-web-application/6501819#6501819)