# creating an email account on mail server by mail api

Tags: java, email, jakarta-ee, jakarta-mail, mail-server

I am creating a web application in which i need to create a form by which user can create an email id on mail server. This is like any email service provider do, like gmail(for creating an email account on their site).

I am new to java mail api. Can anyone provide any hint for this.

Any help will be appreciated.

Thanks...

---

Actually what i want is  a sign up form like what gmail or others provides **to create an email id account** on their servers.

for developing purpose i m using **hmailserve**r.
manually i can create  email ids on this server but i want this in programmatic way.

Comment: have a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6423126/how-to-communicate-with-a-mail-server-through-a-web-application/6501819#6501819

Answer (score 2):

I don't think JavaMail will help here. First, it depends on the mail server you use. Every mail server has different ways to manage user accounts. For example with Postfix you can manage user accounts in a MySQL database (like in [that tutorial](http://workaround.org/ispmail/squeeze/database-setup)). Then you just would have to create database entries. Other mail servers may manage the accounts in a textfile.

Answer (score 1):

AFAIK you can't do it using java mail api alone, you'll need and API for the specific mail server you are using.

Answer (score 0):

Java Mail API will help you out in this. Try these links:
http://www.mkyong.com/java/javamail-api-sending-email-via-gmail-smtp-example/
http://javamail.kenai.com/nonav/javadocs/index.html