# How to manage (create/delete) Email addresses programmatically?

Tags: email, dns, mx-record

I am building a web application that will also allow my users to register/transfer a domain and manage email addresses through my application. However, I'm not exactly sure how to do that yet. I think there are services with APIs that will allow me to register domain names. However, working with DNS, MX records, email addresses and running an email server is something I've never done before. What do I need to know about automating this process of managing email accounts, and what sorts of solutions already exist?

Comment: Can you please share what kind of software you're using for your mail server?

Comment: Interesting Question, I'd imagine getting a better response at _Server Fault_ though

Comment: I don't have any kind of software yet. What would you recommend?

Answer (score 0):

for the email address part, have a look at [How to communicate with a mail server through a web application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6423126/how-to-communicate-with-a-mail-server-through-a-web-application/6501819#6501819)

the dns part is pretty much the same, but you need a dns authoritative server with a database backend, such as [powerdns](http://www.powerdns.com/content/home-powerdns.html) ([database configuration docs](http://doc.powerdns.com/configuring-db-connection.html))
if you don't want to run the dns servers yourself, powerdns also offers hosting with [API access](https://www.powerdns.net/news/powerdns-express-management-api-released.aspx)